# Which geostatistical tools to use to determine surface changes over 40 years?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.1, interpolation, hydrology, geostatistical-analyst

I have a data from the Weather station with SWEmax (snow water equivalent) collected over 40 years. I need to interpolate the data over my river's watershed and then, somehow, determine the differences which might have happened over this time.

- Which tools do I need to use in ArcGIS 10.1 to achieve this?
- Do I need to make z-surfaces first and then take statistics from them?
- Is the best way to show the differences is to use a diagram with years on the x-axis?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you.
But, I think you could for each year creata a Layer.
Then, make a Model Builder to make interpolations.

Comment: Tnx. But its not the case. The main question is: which tools to use to see the differences between interpolated surfaces?

Comment: Differences between surfaces = map algebra (Subtract annual surfaces to see normalized differences)